# eclipse indigo freezes every time while running app in device

Tags: android, eclipse-indigo

Eclipse keep hanging every time when I run the application in  device, I want to check the log messages so I could fix some application bug.

Note: I'm testing in HTC wildfire device.

> System configuration

ubuntu 12.04 
intel core i3 2GB ram and 500 GB HD.

Your suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "freeze"? Does your whole system lock up? Just eclipse? Does your phone freeze? How long do you wait?

Comment: Which is your computer configuration ?

Comment: only my eclipse freezes, and i'am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @iDroid intel core i3 2GB ram 500 GB hard disk

Comment: at any specific time your system get hang ?

Comment: yea when i run my android-application in my device

Comment: @parker.sikand no only my eclipse freezes

Comment: @KarthikRk change your workspace and then try

Comment: @RobinHood should i switch workspace??? sorry i'am very new to this eclipse.how can i change workspace??

Comment: @RobinHood i have switched the workspace but still it continues to freeze when i connect my device

Comment: @KarthikRk [Join this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1278/android-discussion)

Comment: @RobinHood i don't have 20 reputation!!1

Comment: @KarthikRk do one thing, change your eclipse and reintegrate SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great you solved your issue with my provided solution in comment, here I'm Just answering so it will help to other users.

First solution#

Change your workspace and then try out.

Second solution#

Change your eclipse and reintegrate Android SDK and then try out.